# PHP session echo 0

Tags: php, session, opencart

I try set pixel in open cart success page, I have this code:

```
$order_id=(int)$this->session->data['order_id'];
$total_price=$this->cart->getTotal();

$output= "<img src=\"http://track.lead-r.ru/?method=reportAction&transaction_id=". $order_id . "&advertiser_id=2158&offer=2158VxTkF:". $total_price ."\" alt=\"\" style=\"width: 0; height: 0; position:absolute;\" />";
```

it return

```
<img src="http://track.lead-r.ru/?method=reportAction&transaction_id=0&advertiser_id=2158&offer=2158VxTkF:0" alt="" style="width: 0; height: 0; position:absolute;" /><div id="footer">
```

if I set

```
$order_id=123;
$total_price=123;
```

all work nice

```
<img src="http://track.lead-r.ru/?method=reportAction&transaction_id=123&advertiser_id=2158&offer=2158VxTkF:123" alt="" style="width: 0; height: 0; position:absolute;" /><div id="footer">
```

look this http://rghost.ru/57715199

Comment: What is the value of `$this->session->data['order_id'];` without casting it to an int?

Comment: I try <? echo $order_id $total_price ?> this works ok too. Then they "$order_id=(int)$this->session->data['order_id'];" and "$total_price=$this->cart->getTotal();" .I can see their on page, but in view source code empty <div></div>.

Comment: wait I create screnshots

Comment: I share eddard's suspicion in his answer; are you sure you've started the session on that page?

Comment: wondering why you cast to `(int)` when you're concatenating the value

Comment: Look screens http://rghost.ru/57714753

Comment: Session start ok and I create $output before they closing

Comment: $this->session->data['order_id']; generate different numbers, you can see it on the screen 13242 example, but in view sourse code they invisible

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($this->session->data['order_id']);`? This should answer @ChrisForrence and @eddard.stark questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used opencart before but I have used codeigniter and it seems similar, the reason the session is returning 0 is because the session is actually returning false and because you are converting it into int it is showing 0. If it is possible then check, where you have set the session data.